# Mechanism of polymerization of 4-nitroaniline

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, polymers

Does anyone know the mechanism for/the structure of the product of the explosive polymerization of 4-nitroaniline with concentrated sulfuric acid? My guess is that it is some sort of aromatic substitution reaction, leading to a number of benzene rings connected by nitrogens.

Comment: [4-nitroaniline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4-Nitroaniline)?

Comment: [This article](http://scienceline.ucsb.edu/getkey.php?key=3329) by the scientists of the University of California Santa Barbara should pretty much cover your question.

Comment: I was wondering if any more research has been done on the topic.